# react-redux: Call multiple apis parallely on componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

**I need to call two apis parallely**. And this is important as I want to keep the time for the `page to load` to minimum.

1. If I call the two apis (like below) in `componentDidMount` then would it be asynchronous or not.

```
class Test extends Component{
  constructor(args) {
            super(args)
            this.state = {
               ...
            };
            ...
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            //api1() and api2() are like .get(url).then()
            this.props.dispatch(actions.api1())     
            this.props.dispatch(actions.api2())
        }
    }
```

---

**Would call to api1() and api2() will be done in parallel or synchronously?And how can I do that parallely**

---

2. I would also like to mention that my application uses `redux-thunk` something like below but I am not exactly sure what this code is exactly doing. I have read https://redux.js.org/api-reference/applymiddleware that by applying middleware we can make `dispatch` work asynchronously.

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger'
import axios from 'axios'
import { routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux'

import InitialState from './InitialState'


const middleware = [ thunk.withExtraArgument(axios), routerMiddleware(history) ]

/* eslint-enable no-undef */

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    InitialState,
    composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
)

export default store
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default dispatch method in [Reudx](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/src/createStore.js#L140) library is absolutely synchronous.
You can use redux with thunk (or similar `enhancers`) to remove synchronous nature of dispatch, your dispatched events will be wrapped in a Promise when invoking`thunks`.

Additionally, not related to React / Redux:

The browsers have limited number of simultaneous requests per domain which defined in the HTTP specification ([RFC2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.1.4)). Check this [link](http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network&v=0) to see maximum number of simultaneous connections per browser family / version.

Below you can see the maximum number simultaneous connection to the same domain for some of the browsers.

```
+---------+-------------+
| Browser | Connections |
+---------+-------------+
| IE 8, 9 |           6 |
| IE 10   |           8 |
| IE 11   |          13 |
| Chrome  |           6 |
| Safari  |           6 |
| Opera   |           6 |
+---------+-------------+
```

Nice to know: **Synchronous http requests** on the main thread have been **deprecated** due to the negative effects to the user experience [XMLHttpRequest Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests).

Hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 1):

> Would call to api1() and api2() will be done in parallel or
>   synchronously? And how can I do that parallel?

They will be done in parallel.

> I have read https://redux.js.org/api-reference/applymiddleware that by
>   applying middleware we can make dispatch work asynchronously.

Yes, you are right. By default redux is not able to handle asynchronous actions, therefore you should consider to use middlewares like `redux-thunk` or `saga`.